# Webpack not minifying my bundle js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, minify, uglifyjs

I'm now bundling my first project with webpack, everything works as expected except webpack is not minifying my `bundle.min.js` code.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but can't spot the mistake.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here I go w/ my `webpack.config.js`

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/public",
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
      path: __dirname + '/dist',
      filename: "bundle.min.js"
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
         $: "jquery",
         jQuery: "jquery"
     }),
     new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: true
    }),
     new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
       beautify: false,
        mangle: {
          screw_ie8: true,
          keep_fnames: true
        },
        compress: {
          screw_ie8: true
        },
        comments: false
    }),
     new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.min.css"),
     new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              hash: "sha512",
              digest: "hex",
              name: "./img/[hash].[ext]"
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "image-webpack-loader",
            query: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 4,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '75-90',
                speed: 3,
              },
            },
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "./fonts/[name].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Webpack supports minification out of the box. By including the `-p` flag when running `webpack` it will minify your code for you. The `-p` flag is a shortcut for `--optimize-minimize` flag.

Run: `webpack -p`

Comment: I'm just trying to minify `bundle.min.js`, at the moment I'm not bundling any html files. Also, I just ran `webpack -p` it builds as expected, but again, my  `bundle.min.js` file is no minified and has all the comments.

Comment: it might be the `debug` option that's interferring, the 2 do seem somewhat opposites

Comment: I just removed the debug option as well as the LoaderOptionsPlugin (just in case) but still, not minified, this is driving me nuts

Comment: Thank y'all, with the latest Webpack upgrades, this issue is gone for me. Happy 2019!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well with Webpack 4. It went away after upgrading to Webpack 4.28.2.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. It started working after providing mode config value as production.

```
module.exports = {
    // webpack config
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
};

// command NODE_ENV=production webpack
```